# Calculate Luminosity of a star from the Hipparcos catalogue

Tags: luminosity, star-catalogues, hipparcos

Is it possible to calculate the star's luminosity based on the data in the Hipparcos catalogue? Currently I'm using this algorithm, I have even fitted the bolometric correction to the Johnson V band (500-580 nm) but it still gives inaccurate results:
(pseudocode)

```
set BV,apparentMagnitude,parallax
Temperature=BVtoT(BV)
distance=1000/parallax
absoluteBolMagnitude=apparentMagnitude-5*log10(distance/10)+bolometricCorrection(Temperature)-bolometricCorrection(5800) //5800 is the temp. of the Sun
Luminosity=2.512^(4.83-absoluteBolMagnitude)  //4.83 is the abs.bol.mag. of the Sun
```

Bolometric correction used:

```
 Temp|Correction
 1000:-15.792870388279043
 2000: -4.6660448937937975
 3000: -1.6491013655965077
 4000: -0.4942579918145218
 5000: -0.013012417388273079
 6000:  0.16898491871093757
 7000:  0.20207943778842052
 8000:  0.1560070183734874
 9000:  0.06632925066158046
10000: -0.04757422843666781
11000: -0.17462275518259318
12000: -0.3082568327994979
13000: -0.44449896986079906
14000: -0.5809025615684753
15000: -0.715956305710435
```

B-V to Temperature conversion:

```
  B-V|Temperature (Kelvin)
-0.30:33605
-0.25:22695   B-V|Temperature (Kelvin)
-0.20:16954|+0.90: 5064
-0.15:13674|+1.00: 4817
-0.10:11677|+1.20: 4359
-0.05:10395|+1.40: 3944
+0.00: 9531|+1.60: 3568
+0.10: 8455|+1.80: 3229
+0.20: 7767|+2.00: 2921
+0.30: 7218|+2.20: 2643
+0.40: 6728|+2.40: 2392
+0.50: 6284|+2.60: 2164
+0.60: 5893|+2.80: 1958
+0.70: 5597|+3.00: 1772
+0.80: 5324|+3.00: 1603
```

Calculations for Betelgeuse:

```
BV=1.5
apparentMagnitude=0.45
parallax=7.63 mas
Temperature=BVtoT(BV)=3751 K
distance=1000/parallax=131 parsec
absoluteBolMagnitude=apparentMagnitude-5*log10(distance/10)+bolometricCorrection(Temperature)-bolometricCorrection(5800)
                 =0.45-5*log10(131/10)+(-0.6952)-(+0.1477)
                 =0.45-5.5874-0.6952-0.1477=-5.9803
Luminosity=2.512^(4.75-absoluteBolMagnitude)
          =19600 L_sun //4x times smaller that expected
```

Is there any way that I could improve on this?

Comment: I can't see why you are using a bolometric correction for 5800K when calculating a bolometric magnitude. Are you using Johnson V band data? That isn't what Hipparcos measured?